# Remove unvanted clicks in generated sound in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I am having the following problem when generating sound wave in Flash.
This is the generator part :

```
const SAMPLING_RATE:int = 44100;
const TWO_PI:Number = 2 * Math.PI;
const TWO_PI_OVER_SR:Number = TWO_PI / SAMPLING_RATE;
const SAMPLE_SIZE:int = 8192 / 4;


function generateSine(fq:Number):ByteArray
{
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var sample:Number;
var amp:Number = 1;


for (var i:int=0; i<SAMPLE_SIZE; i++)
{
    sample = amp* Math.sin(i  * TWO_PI_OVER_SR *   fq  );
    bytes.writeFloat(sample);
}


bytes.position = 0;
return bytes;
 }
```

and this is the playback part:

```
function playbackSampleHandler(event:SampleDataEvent):void
{
var sample:Number;

for (var i:int = 0; i <  SAMPLE_SIZE && soundData.bytesAvailable; i++)
{
    sample = soundData.readFloat();
    event.data.writeFloat(sample);
    event.data.writeFloat(sample);
}
 }



 function onClickPlay(e:MouseEvent)
 {
soundData= new ByteArray();
    var sound:ByteArray= new ByteArray();
    sound=generateSine(440);
soundData.writeBytes(sound,0,sound.length);
soundData.position = 0;
morphedSound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playbackSampleHandler);
soundChannel = morphedSound.play();             
 }
```

Quick explanation:
I basically write values for the sine function into the ByteArray and than playback handler reads that array and plays back the sound. I write only one 8192/4 sample buffer.

Problem:
My problem is that when you do this there are annoying clicks on the end of sound, which are the artifacts of sine wave being cut on a value other than 0. So my question is how can I avoid this?

Bonus:
I would also like to know how can I generate for example exactly 100 ms of sine wave when buffers in Flash are so strict i.e. from   2048 to 8192 ?

Links:
If it helps my code is based on this tutorial
http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2669
and my own explorations.

Comment: I did notice the downvote which I don't mind but I don't know why someone downvoted this because the question is quite detailed including code and it shows research effort? If someone has pointers on how to make this question better or if it's a duplicate please write a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to preserve phase of sine wave that occurs at the end of your sample data processing. Otherwise your sine wave is not continued smoothly and you get the clicks you speak of.

```
var totalSamples:int=0;
function generateSine(fq:Number):ByteArray
{
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var sample:Number;
var amp:Number = 1;


for (var i:int=0; i<SAMPLE_SIZE; i++)
{
    sample = amp* Math.sin((i+totalSamples)  * TWO_PI_OVER_SR *   fq  );
    // this uses stored phase ^^^
    bytes.writeFloat(sample);
}
totalSamples+=SAMPLE_SIZE; // this preserves phase between subsequent samples

bytes.position = 0;
return bytes;
```

}

Update: I've noticed you are calling generator twice in a row - this is awful. You must never call a function twice if you only need one result of its work.

function onClickPlay(e:MouseEvent)
   {
     soundData= generateSine(440); // why using writeBytes if we can just use assignment?
     soundData.position = 0;
     morphedSound.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, playbackSampleHandler);
     soundChannel = morphedSound.play();
   }

Also, to make the sound end with a full (half-)wave of sound and remove the last click you need, use this technique:

```
function generateSine(fq:Number,cleanFinish:Boolean=false):ByteArray
{
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
var sample:Number;
var amp:Number = 1;


for (var i:int=0; i<SAMPLE_SIZE; i++)
{
    sample = amp* Math.sin((i+totalSamples)  * TWO_PI_OVER_SR *   fq  );
    // this uses stored phase ^^^
    bytes.writeFloat(sample);
    if (cleanFinish) 
      if ((Math.abs(sample)<(SAMPLING_RATE/fq/3))&&(i>SAMPLE_SIZE-SAMPLING_RATE/fq)) break; 
    // this triggers a drop if we are sampling the last wave already
}
totalSamples+=i; // this preserves phase between subsequent samples

bytes.position = 0;
return bytes;
```

}

Call this function with an optional Boolean parameter set to true to receive correctly terminated wave.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Well this does solve a part of the problem but there is still annoying click on the end of the sound. So the problem actually is how do I end a sound only when the Math.sin(x)=0 ?

Comment: Okay, you'll have to truncate your ByteArray to the last about-zero position, or instruct the generator to only generate full sine waves  at least when you request it to end generation.

Comment: Thank you!I am trying the first approach with truncating and also lowering volume gradually towards the end of sample which is giving me ok results. How would I do the other approach to instruct to only generate full waves?

Comment: I am going to test the suggestion in few minutes. Calling twice part was just me being lazy to introduce a variable and copy pasted that by mistake here, that was changed in the code few minutes after. Thanks for pointing it out thou. I updated the code in the question. A am appending bytes instead of assigning because I want to generate sequences of notes and than play that simple "tune" later.

Comment: Okay about appending, it's just that the code states "new ByteArray() then instantly "writeBytes".

Comment: I tried as you suggested and there is still a click at the end of sound. Am I missing something? Why are you dividing by 3 in (SAMPLING_RATE/fq/3)) ?

Comment: The correct division should be /8 or maybe /4. This formula should determine the difference between the sample below zero and sample above zero, thus if its absolute is less than this, we can stop sampling, so the next sample will be zero. The next click could rise because of this only checking for a half-wave, not a full wave.

Comment: It's not even entering the block with break. Is this supposed to detect close to zero value for the sample and stop writing to the bytearray?

Answer (score 0):

All SAMPLE_SIZE values of "sample" must be split in three pieces:
The first and the third piece must have 250 values each and the middle one
the rest: SAMPLE_SIZE - 500. Make this as follows:
   Generate an array of 250 values between 0 and .996 with step .004 :
I mean: .000, .004, .008, ... , .996, and fill with them an array, say, mod[i]
with i from zero to 249.(mod is for modulation...)
   Modify initial loop as below and so will result a fade from 0 to (+/-)amp(first 250 values) then the rest of values up to the last 250 remain (+/-)amp and, finally, the last 250 values have a fade from (+/-)amp to 0. The nasty clicks remain...history! I Hope this help.

```
function generateSine(fq:Number):ByteArray
{
   var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
   var sample:Number;
   var amp:Number = 1;


 for (var i:int=0; i< 250; i++)
   {
      sample = amp* Math.sin(i  * TWO_PI_OVER_SR *   fq  ) * mod[i];
      bytes.writeFloat(sample);
   }

   for (var i:int=250; i<SAMPLE_SIZE - 250; i++)
   {
      sample = amp* Math.sin(i  * TWO_PI_OVER_SR *   fq  );
      bytes.writeFloat(sample);
   }

   for (var i:int=SAMPLE_SIZE - 250; i<SAMPLE_SIZE; i++)
   {
      sample = amp* Math.sin(i  * TWO_PI_OVER_SR *   fq  ) * (.996 - mod[i]);
      bytes.writeFloat(sample);
   }


   bytes.position = 0;
   return bytes;
}
```